# Rollup with CommonJS, import and exports with treeshaking

Tags: javascript, commonjs, rollup, tree-shaking

I'm trying to get rollup, commonjs, es6 and tree shaking working correctly.

Currently, I have the following build script:

```
'use strict';

const rollup = require('rollup');
const resolve = require('rollup-plugin-node-resolve');
const commonjs = require('rollup-plugin-commonjs');

rollup.rollup({
  input: 'main.js',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [
    {
      transform(code, id) {
        return code;
      }
    },
    resolve({
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    }),
    commonjs({
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    })
  ]
})
.then(({ generate }) => generate({
  format: 'iife',
  name: 'test',
}))
.then(({ code }) => console.log(code));
```

which loads the following `main.js` file

```
const { firstFunction } = require('./exports');

firstFunction();
```

and the `export.js` file

```
export function firstFunction() {
  return this.name;
}

export function secondFunction() {
  return this.name;
}
```

outputs the following:

```
var test = (function () {
'use strict';

function firstFunction$1() {
  return this.name;
}

function secondFunction() {
  return this.name;
}


var exports$1 = Object.freeze({
    firstFunction: firstFunction$1,
    secondFunction: secondFunction
});

var require$$0 = ( exports$1 && undefined ) || exports$1;

const { firstFunction } = require$$0;

firstFunction();

var main = {

};

return main;

}());
```

I am unsure if this is the correct behaviour, I was assuming that I would be able to use tree-shaking with the es6 `export.js` file and therefore not need to import the `secondFunction()` from `export.js` in our bundled code.

I have tried a number of combinations of settings but nothing seems to be able to get tree-shaking to work.

**It's worth noting** that I'm using commonjs on the server and trying to use the same file bundled on the client - this is why I have a mix of cjs and es6.

Comment: use import instead of require if possible

Comment: @Lux I need to use commonjs for main.js as it's running on node.

Comment: This doesn't makes sense if you use `export` in the `export.js` (assuming the missing `s` is a typo). Also you transpile that `import`. The entire idea of rollup is to remove all `import`s and replace them with one single IIFE (or whatever you want)

Comment: The thing is, I'm using commonjs on the server and I want to share this piece of code with the client (it's a view file written in with jsx). If we're saying that 100% there is no way to get the commonjs to treeshake, then i'll look at other solutions but the fact that the cjs is requiring in an es6 named export file - I assumed it would work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by Lux in comments, the problem is you're mixing cjs and ES modules. It seems the `rollup-plugin-commonjs` does not treeshake the imports.

You should first bundle your files with rollup and use cjs as output format. You then `require` the bundle.

That should get your javascript treeshaken and ready for node.

Comment: As I mentioned in my other comment, I'm using commonjs on the server and I want to share this piece of code with the client (it's a view file written in with jsx). If we're saying that 100% there is no way to get the commonjs to treeshake, then i'll look at other solutions but the fact that the cjs is requiring in an es6 named export file - I assumed it would work.

Comment: I don't quite follow you. Can't you change the `require` in `main.js` to an `import`?

Comment: Nope. Because then node wouldn't be able to run it. es6 named exports aren't available in node, yet.

Comment: If you use rollup on `main.js` (and it uses exclusively ES module syntax), you will get a module usable in node with the benefits of treeshaking.

Comment: I know, but i really would just like to use commonjs on the server and transpile it to use on the client.